# merge two data.frame with condition in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I would like to compare two data sets `df1` and `df2` in such a way that, the unique characters in `df2$ID` should be added as a new column in `df1` and assign `df2$Xp` value for each gene, if the coordinates of `df1` overlaps with the coordinates of df2:

```
 df1 <- read.table(text="
        Gene     chr  Start End 
        Gm12724   4  1000   1105    
        Zfhx2     4  1254   1369    
        Usp17lc   7  5004   5412
        Lingo1    7  5698   5789
        Sart3     7  5987   6041
        Olfr978   4  1452   1564
    ", header=T)


    df2 <- read.table(text="
        ID      chr Start   End     Xp
        S8411     4  989    1258   0.312
        S8411     4  1300   1800   0.144
        S8411     7  5641   6874   0.136
        S8413     4  1307   1360  -1.999
",header=T)
```

expected output

```
 df3 <- read.table(" 
        Gene    chr   Start End   S8411  S8413
        Gm12724   4  1000   1105  0.312     0
        Zfhx2     4  1294   1369  0.144     -1.999
        Usp17lc   7  5004   5412    0       0
        Lingo1    7  5698   5789  0.136     0
        Sart3     7  5987   6041  0.136     0
        Olfr978   4  1452   1564   0.144    0
",header=T)
```

Comment: @akrun. I'm aware of findOverlaps which gives the overlapping region.  from that how can i create a new dataset by adding  unique(df2$ID) as new column in df1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1),chr, Start, End)
setkey(setDT(df2), chr, Start, End)
res <- foverlaps(df1, df2,  type='any')[
   ( Start > i.Start| End> i.End)|is.na(Start)][,
   c('Start', 'End') := list(i.Start, i.End)][,7:8 := NULL]
dcast(res, ...~ID, value.var='Xp', fill=0)[, -7, with=FALSE]
#    chr Start  End    Gene S8411  S8413
#1:   4  1000 1105 Gm12724 0.312  0.000
#2:   4  1254 1369   Zfhx2 0.144 -1.999
#3:   4  1452 1564 Olfr978 0.144  0.000
#4:   7  5004 5412 Usp17lc 0.000  0.000
#5:   7  5698 5789  Lingo1 0.136  0.000
#6:   7  5987 6041   Sart3 0.136  0.000
```

Comment: akrun@ getting error message:  Duplicate columns are not allowed in overlap joins. This may change in the future.

Comment: @beginner Based on the example you provided, I am not getting any errors.   Also please check  whether the genomicranges solution works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648127/find-overlapping-regions-and-extract-respective-value/29649005?noredirect=1#comment48108626_29649005

Comment: it worked for the example. But when i tried it with my original dataset its getting error.

Comment: @beginner I am not sure what the problem is without an example that gives the error.  Can you try the solution in the link?

Comment: the link doesn't provide solution to my query.

Comment: @beginner the `mergeByOverlaps` gets 7 rows of output and if you use `dcast` it will give the result (from the comments of zx8754, I didn't test it)

Comment: could you tell what is the function of : ( Start > i.Start| End> i.End)|is.na(Start)][,
   c('Start', 'End') := list(i.Start, i.End)][,7:8 := NULL]

Comment: @beginner After the join, we get two additional columns,i.Start and i.End, I was trying to subset the dataset as some genes have more than one row