# Let a for loop add all results to an existing data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, rbind

I want that the results, which are generated by my for-loop are passed into one single `data.frame`. Therefore I created one empty data.frame like this:

```
result <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 1))
```

and then matched the names of the columns with the names of the `data.frame`, which is going to be searched:

```
names(result) <- names(example)
```

My for-loop should iterate through a list of values and check the input `data.frame` for values that meet the conditions and then add the entire row of this value to my empty `data.frame`

```
lpos
[1] 5

for(i in lpos){
indx <- sapply(example[,4], function(x) (x > minpos[i]) & (x < maxpos[i])) 
newrow <- example[indx,]
result = rbind(result, newrow)
}
```

So my expected output would be that I got a `data.frame`, containing all results. But it seems that this code overwrites the added rows everytime and I just got the last iteration saved in my `data.frame`.

What can I do to prevent this code from overwriting the existing results?
So my data looks like this:

```
> head(example[1:4,-9])
      V1       V2   V3    V4    V5   V6 V7 V8
1 Spenn-ch00 AUGUSTUS mRNA  5691  9072 0.84  -  .
2 Spenn-ch00 AUGUSTUS mRNA 11246 12192 0.17  -  .
3 Spenn-ch00 AUGUSTUS mRNA 12799 15702 0.33  -  .
4 Spenn-ch00 AUGUSTUS mRNA 15752 18482 0.48  -  .
```

Comment: Why use `O` within loop, easily misread as `0` zero.

Comment: Please add output of `head(example)` or `dput(example)` to the post, so we know about your data. Probably you can avoid for loop altogther.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think you are looking for merge on ranges - see [example on mergeByOverlaps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29649005/680068)

Comment: So I posted the head of my `data.frame`. And yes that looks like it would be the right thing for me to use!

Comment: Looks like you just have to change to `for(i in 1 : lpos){...`  --  or is `lpos` a vector? More details would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @vaettchen that was indeed the problem of the code. I have not thought of it just taking the one number. Now it works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I just took the one number contained in `lpos` instead of using the range from 1 to `lpos`

```
lpos
[1] 5

for(i in 1:lpos){
indx <- sapply(example[,4], function(x) (x > minpos[i]) & (x < maxpos[i])) 
newrow <- example[indx,]
result = rbind(result, newrow)
}
```

When the code is like this now, it works perfectly.