# Cross-referencing data frames without using for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

Im having an issue with speed of using for loops to cross reference 2 data frames. The overall aim is to identify rows in data frame 2 that lie between coordinates specified in data frame 1 (and meet other criteria). e.g. df1:

```
    chr     start       stop        strand
1   chr1    179324331   179327814   +
2   chr21   45176033    45182188    +
3   chr5    126887642   126890780   +
4   chr5    148730689   148734146   +
```

df2:

```
    chr     start       strand
1   chr1    179326331   +
2   chr21   45175033    +
3   chr5    126886642   +
4   chr5    148729689   +
```

My current code for this is:

```
for (index in 1:nrow(df1)) { 
  found_miRNAs <- ""
  curr_row = df1[index, ]; 
for (index2 in 1:nrow(df2)){
    curr_target = df2[index2, ]
    if (curr_row$chrm == curr_target$chrm & curr_row$start < curr_target$start & curr_row$stop > curr_target$start & curr_row$strand == curr_target$strand) {
      found_miRNAs <- paste(found_miRNAs, curr_target$start, sep=":")
    }
  }
  curr_row$miRNAs <- found_miRNAs
  found_log <- rbind(Mcf7_short_aUTRs2,curr_row)
}
```

My actual data frames are 400 lines for df1 and > 100 000 lines for df2 and I am hoping to do 500 iterations, so, as you can imagine this unworkably slow. I'm relatively new to R so any hints for functions that may increase the efficiency of this would be great.

Comment: See [this post regarding merging genomic regions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648127/find-overlapping-regions-and-extract-respective-value)

Comment: Or the answer (with the more upvotes) below it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into two of the most common mistakes people make when coming to R from another programming language. Using for loops instead of vector-based operations and dynamically appending to a data object.  I'd suggest as you get more fluent you take some time to read [Patrick Burns' R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), it provides some interesting insight into these and other problems.

As @David Arenburg and @zx8754 have pointed out in the comments above there are specialized packages that can solve the problem, and the `data.table` package and @David's approach can be very efficient for larger datasets.  But for your case base R can do what you need it to very efficiently as well.  I'll document one approach here, with a few more steps than necessary for clarity, just in case you're interested:

```
set.seed(1001)

ranges <- data.frame(beg=rnorm(400))
ranges$end <- ranges$beg + 0.005

test <- data.frame(value=rnorm(100000))
##  Add an ID field for duplicate removal:
test$ID <- 1:nrow(test)


##  This is where you'd set your criteria.  The apply() function is just 
##      a wrapper for a for() loop over the rows in the ranges data.frame:
out <- apply(ranges, MAR=1, function(x) test[ (x[1] < test$value & x[2] > test$value), "ID"])

selected <- unlist(out)
selected <- unique( selected )

selection <- test[ selected, ]
```

Comment: My apologies to @Jonathan Nieves, the original accepted answer reversed the data.frame objects that were being checked against each other.  I've reversed these but the core of the solution remains the same and still is relatively efficient for such a small data set.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not fast enough, but probably faster and a lot easier to read:

```
df1 <- data.frame(foo=letters[1:5], start=c(1,3,4,6,2), end=c(4,5,5,9,4))
df2 <- data.frame(foo=letters[1:5], start=c(3,2,5,4,1))
where <- sapply(df2$start, function (x) which(x >= df1$start & x <= df1$end))
```

This will give you a list of the relevant rows in df1 for each row in df2. I just tried it with 500 rows in df1 and 50000 in df2. It finished in a second or two.

To add criteria, change the inner function within `sapply`. If you then want to put `where` into your second data frame, you could do e.g.

```
df2$matching_rows <- sapply(where, paste, collapse=":")
```

But you probably want to keep it as a list, which is a natural data structure for it.

Actually, you can even have a list column it in the data frame:

```
df2$matching_rows <- where
```

though this is quite unusual.